# Symfony 2 : How to correctly add an element in collection in the form

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, prototype

In a form of entityA I'd like to be able to add some form of entityB.

I know how to show one form but when I put the attribute 'collection' with 'allow_add'... it doesn't add anything but an empty

here is my view :

```
<.form action="{{ path('our_bundle_building_entityACreate')}}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} >
{{ form_widget(form) }}

{{ form_row(form.entity) }}

<ul id="price-fields-list" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.entityB.vars.prototype) | e }}">
    {% for entityB in form.entityB %}
        <li>
            {{ form_errors(entityB) }}
            {{ form_widget(entityB) }}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
<a href="#" id="add-another-entityB">Add another entityB price</a>

<input type="submit" />
<./form>

<.script type="text/javascript">
var entityBCount = '{{ form.entityB | length }}';

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#add-another-entityB').click(function() {
        var entityBList = jQuery('#entityB-fields-list');

        var newWidget = entityBList.attr('data-prototype');

        newWidget = newWidget.replace(/__name__/g, entityBCount);
        entityBCount++;

        var newLi = jQuery('<li></li>').html(newWidget);
        newLi.appendTo(jQuery('#entityB-fields-list'));

        return false;
    });
})
<./script>`
```

my form of entityB is nicely working so I won't show it ( only a few usual inputs )

my form of entityA in the buildForm :

```
->add('entityB', 
                'collection', 
                array('type' => new entityBType($this->id),
                      'allow_add' => true,
                      'allow_delete'  => true,
                      'by_reference' => false,));
```

By the way, I didn't really understood the "prototype" so the problem may come from here.

Thanks and regards,

Me :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just embed that one form, the simplest way is to do this:

```
...    

->add('entityB', new entityBType($this->id));
```

Comment: I need a collection of form, as I said, I already knew that and that's working, but collection isn't

Comment: Are you actually building a collection of entityB forms? Because that's not clear from your example above. If it's just one form you want to embed, then functionally, a "collection" is not necessary. A collection of one child form is not a collection. :/ In that case, just make the entityB form type a child property of the parent entityA form type. Otherwise, look in your log file(s) in `app/logs` and see if Symfony is complaining about your collection configuration. The snippet above isn't sufficient to determine what's wrong.

Comment: In fact entityA has a relation one to many with entityB so I think I need a collection. I'll check the app/logs